# How to derive multi-variable function $z=\sin(\sqrt{u^2-r})$, where $u=\sin x$ and $ r=e^x $?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to derive multi-variable function $z=\sin(\sqrt{u^2-r})$, where $u=\sin x$ and $ r=e^x $?

I have been given task to derive this function by using "the law of derivation of two variable composite function" (when translated literally from my native language).
I know that there is General Leibniz rule, which states that $$(uv)^{(n)}=u^{(n)}v+C^1_n u^{(n-1)}v^{(1)}+\cdots+C^{n-1}_nu^{(1)}v^{(n-1)}+uv^{(n)}$$

But can that be useful in this case?

Comment: $dz/dx = (dz/du)*(du/dx) + (dz/dr)*(dr/dx)$

Comment: This is not a multivariable problem : $z$ is just a function of $x$. Using JJacquelin's suggestion will be a very good idea.

Comment: I know this is strange, but those where the requirements.

Comment: As @ClaudeLeibovici say this is not a multivariable problem. If you want to see more clear, then replace your functions in terms of $x$ and you would obtain a function of a single variable.

Comment: I hope you like your answer @KristiansKuhta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use the chain rule procedure to answer this question, and to do this I will first show you how to use it.
\begin{align}\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{dz}{dr}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\end{align}
To answer your question one may begin by doing the following:
\begin{align}\frac{dz}{dx}&=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{u^2-r})}{2\sqrt{u^2-r}}2\sin(x)\cos(x)- \frac{\cos(\sqrt{u^2-r})}{2\sqrt{u^2-r}}e^x \\ &\text{Now plugging in the $u= \sin(x)$, and r=$e^x$} \\ \frac{dz}{dx}&=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-e^x)}}{2\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-e^x}}(2\sin(x)\cos(x)-e^x) \end{align}